# ajaxのdoneに入れるjs条件式について

Tags: javascript

**JavaScript**

```
var expr = 'Papayas';
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
   <a herf="">リンク</a>
    break;
  case 'Papayas':
    <div>準備</div>
    break;
}
```

**Ajax**

```
.done((data)=>
$('.result').append('<div></div><div></div>')

})
```

JavaScriptのswitch条件式をAjaxのdoneに埋め込みたいです。
以下のように埋め込んだのですが、正しくはどのように入れたらいいのか分かりません教えていただきたいです。

**JavaScript**

```
.done((data)=>
var expr = 'Papayas';
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
   <a herf="">リンク</a>
    break;
  case 'Papayas':
    <div>準備</div>
    break;
}
$('.result').append('')

})
```

Comment: ajaxからの戻り値「data」をつかってswitchの条件式を作りたいと読み取りましたが、「data」の中身はどんなものになるでしょうか？（例えば、json形式で{"expr":"Papayas"}になってる、等）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常通り変数を設定して、変数でappendに渡して上げましょう。

```
.done((data)=>
  var expr = 'Papayas';
  var append_content;
  switch (expr) {
    case 'Oranges':
      append_content = '<a herf="">リンク</a>'
      break;
    case 'Papayas':
      append_content = '<div>準備</div>';
      break;
  }
  $('.result').append(append_content);

})
```